# Module not found when running uvicorn

Tags: python, fastapi, modulenotfounderror, uvicorn

I have created a FastAPI app that is using the python library here

https://github.com/swar/nba_api

When I run the command

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

I get that the module nba_api is not found. I have installed this module using pip and am currently using a Python virtualenv (can see the nba_api in the lib/python3.10/site-packages file). When I just run the main.py file using

```
python3 main.py
```

the module is found. Any ideas why this would be the case?

Ran

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

was expecting my web server to load and to be able to hit the API endpoints that would use this python library, however uvicorn server failed to load.

Can call library if I invoke using

```
python3 main.py
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

My crystal ball says you've installed `uvicorn` outside the virtualenv; if that's the case, uninstall it from the ambient environment, then install it only in the virtualenv, and try again.

Answer (score 2):

`.venv` is sometimes behaving in a strange way. So, I think, if uvicorn was already installed previously, even if you installed it in the virtual environment, it picks up from the base/root environment.

So, uninstalling uvicorn package from base/root environment, and then installing it again in virtual environment should solve the issue.